# Unity3D: Returning back to idle state animation

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with returning back to my idle state animation in my game. This [video](https://youtu.be/TAM3hP-m3bo) is an example of what my problem is. My player doesn't go back to idle state animation, which I did try adding this to my code:

```
anim.SetBool ("walking", false);
```

(This is placed near to the end of my [code](http://pasteboard.co/cc1n2jEaG.png))

But this [happens](https://youtu.be/PagWMwU7QGk). Which is not what I want. In the [first](https://youtu.be/TAM3hP-m3bo) video I showed you, it shows me clicking the [walking parameter off](http://pasteboard.co/cbS0YMEtm.png) so that I can show you what my animation would look like if my player stop once it reached it's destination.In the video you can see that my player faced the wrong way after walking down and up, it faced this [way](http://pasteboard.co/cbT1OhMaw.png) and that [way](http://pasteboard.co/cbUgJcSpB.png), which I would also like to fix, but have no idea how to. So can anyone help me with both of my problems, which is:

1. Returning back to idle animation once my player reaches it's destination.
2. And making sure that my player face the correct direction as it is suppose to. My player's sprite [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tG6I.png)

Here is my code:

**Second Edit**

```
private Animator anim;
public float speed = 15f;
private Vector3 target;
private bool touched;
private bool playerMovementRef;

void Start () 
{
    target = transform.position;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void Update () 
{

if(transform.position == target)
{
    anim.SetBool ("walking", false);
}
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))
       {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition.z = 10; // distance from the camera
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);
        target.z = transform.position.z;

        var movementDirection = (target - transform.position).normalized;
            Vector3 animDirection = Vector3.zero;
            // Use >= to default to horizontal on both being equal

        if (movementDirection.x > movementDirection.y) 
            animDirection.x = 1;
        else
            animDirection.y = 1;

        anim.SetBool ("walking", true);
        anim.SetFloat ("SpeedX", movementDirection.x);
        anim.SetFloat ("SpeedY", movementDirection.y);

        Debug.LogFormat ("X: {0}, Y: {1}", movementDirection.x, movementDirection.y);

        if (movementDirection.x > 0)
        {
            anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", 1f);
        }
        else if (movementDirection.x < 0) 
        {
            anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", -1f);
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (movementDirection.y > 0)
            {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", 1f);
            } 
            else if (movementDirection.y < 0)
            {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", -1f);
            } 
            else 
            {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", 0f);
            } 
        }   
    } 
    else 
    {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Detect if the player is in current destination or not. You can get the current destination from `target`. If it's in current destination then make "walking" bool false. Facing on correct direction should be working fine with it.

Put this block in `Update()`:

```
if(transform.position == target)
{
    anim.SetBool ("walking", false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I have tried it out what you have suggested, but I'm still having [problems](https://youtu.be/mJA5E-0iYb4). Maybe it's because I place the block you gave me at the wrong place, if you look back at my question above you can see that I have edited the code to what it looks like now.